# Make a .deb for a Node.js application

Tags: deb, nodejs

How I make a .deb for a Node.js application that installs Node.js and its required npm modules on dpkg -i?

Which is the place in the filesystem where I have to put this application? (/opt,/usr/local).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an article + screencast on the subject:

[How to create a .deb for NodeJS apps](https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-create-a-debian-installer.html)

Answer (score -2):

I know this is kind of late.

Here is a ppa repo that might help you:
https://launchpad.net/~chris-lea/+archive/node.js/

This installs node to a standard location. I consider installing with npm to local directories (part of the application) the best practice.

Source: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

Comment: Your answer isn't related to my question. I asked how build a .deb for a Node.js app, not install Node.js from a .deb. But thanks anyway :D